# Can't get cn from Policy Response of OpenAM

Tags: openam

All.

I’m trying to config OpenAM, J2EEAgent and OpenIG. I want to get cn when I get Policy Response of OpenAM. so I config com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.fetch.mode
= HTTP_HEADER. However I can’t get cn in the Policy Response.

I have two questions.

1, How do I configure to get cn in the Policy Response?

2, I search uid(OpenIG managed) from cn using SqlAttributesFilter
 when OpenIG get the Policy Response. I made config.json of OpenIG. Please check it.

```
{
    "_comment" : "Sample OpenIG config for form login.",
    "heap":[
            {
                "name":"DispatchHandler",
                "type":"DispatchHandler",
                "config":{
                    "bindings":[
                        {
                        "condition": "${matches(exchange.request.uri.path,'^/openig') != null}",
                            "handler":"LoginChain"
                        },
                        {
                            "handler":"OutgoingChain"
                        }
                    ],
                    "baseURI":"http://test.co.jp:7070/"
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"LoginChain",
                "type":"Chain",
                "config":{
                    "filters":["SqlAttributesFilter"],
                    "handler":"LoginRedirectHandler"
                }
            },
            {
                    "name": "SqlAttributesFilter",
                    "type": "SqlAttributesFilter",
                    "config": {
                        "dataSource": "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgresql",
                        "preparedStatement":
                            "SELECT uid
                                    FROM user_table WHERE cn = ?;",
                        "parameters": [
                             "${exchange.request.headers['cn'][0]}"
                        ],
                       "target" : "${exchange.credentials}"
                    }
            },
            {
                "name":"LoginRedirectHandler",
                "type":"StaticResponseHandler",
                "config":{
                    "status":302,
                    "reason":"Found",
                    "headers":{
                        "Location":[
                            "http://test.co.jp:5050/testsp/index.html?j_site=${exchange.credentials.site}&j_uid=${exchange.credentials.uid}"
                        ],
                        "Cache-Control":["no-cache"],
                        "Pragma":["no-cache"]

                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"OutgoingChain",
                "type":"Chain",
                "config":{
                    "filters":[
                        "CaptureFilter"
                    ],
                    "handler":"ClientHandler"
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"ClientHandler",
                "type":"ClientHandler",
                "config":{
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"CaptureFilter",
                "type":"CaptureFilter",
                "config":{
                    "captureEntity":true,
                    "file":"/home/test/.openig/config/gateway.log"
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"LogSink",
                "comment":"Default sink for logging information.",
                "type":"ConsoleLogSink",
                "config":{
                    "level":"DEBUG"
                }
            }
    ],
    "handler": "DispatchHandler"
}
```

Please give me your help.
Regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) by modifying the policy that suppose to match your protected resource, and adding "cn" to the list of attributes.

Alternatively you could just modify your agent configuration, so instead of using response attributes, you set up attribute mapping for profile attributes.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I nail it!